# What test to use to compare two groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, spss

I have two random groups of participants each asked the same framing question, one group in a positive and one group in a negative manner. How do I test my data for normality and hence decide what test to run in SPSS? I am thinking either an independent $t$-test if normally distributed or a $u$-test if not.

Comment: What is nature of the measured variable ?  That is often dispositive as to what test is appropriate.

Comment: The participants are asked in one of 2 ways how likely they are to eat a certain food, the answer is given as a percentage.  I have 429 responses.

Comment: What is the null hypothesis? That the expected values of the two groups are equal?

Comment: So each participant answers e.g. 30 % ?  What are their options ?  Like, can they answer any percent between 0 % and 100 % ?  Or are there limited options ?

Comment: Each participant can answer 0-100%, the null hypothesis is that both groups answers are equal. Thanks for your help. I just need to run a test to show significance. I have spss, but I am not sure what test to run or I interpret if the data is normally distributed. (Due to there being two groups each asked the same question but one in a more leading manner!)

Comment: Each participant can answer 0-100%, the null hypothesis is that both groups answers are equal. Thanks for your help. I just need to run a test to show significance. I have spss, but I am not sure what test to run or I interpret if the data is normally distributed. (Due to there being two groups each asked the same question but one in a more leading manner!)

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: With each participant being able to respond from 0 to 100 % , you can probably treat the dependent variable as continuous. ... There are different ways you can compare the responses from two groups.  If you want better advice, you might include histograms of your data in your question.  It's possible that *t*-test will accomplish what you want.  But if you want a non-parametric approach, you could use the Mann-Whitney test in SPSS.  You could also compare medians, or use other tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a t-test to test whether the means from the two groups are equal or not. That is:
$$
H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2 \\
H_1: \mu_1\neq\mu_2
$$

Note that you do not need your data to be normally distributed. [The normality assumption of the t-test is concerned with the distribution of the statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Assumptions). In your case that is the mean, which we know (from the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)) to be approximately normally distributed with relatively large sample sizes (which you have).

PS: Even if your variables represent probabilities, in my opinion it is absolutely fine to treat them as continuous variables on a 0-100 scale in this case.

Comment: I did not downvote this answer, and I wish whoever did would leave a comment of explanation.  But I do think it's generally bad advice to ignore the distribution of the data and move to a *t*-test.  Depending on the distribution, comparing means may not be the most desired approach even if the distribution of the *t* statistic is approximately normal with a large sample size.

Comment: Thanks @SalMangiafico – I also wish whoever downvoted my answer would leave a comment. I agree with the advice you give, and also think we are missing valuable details from OP to be able to provide a good answer. It was probably a mistake from my part to post one regardless.